# c# configurar puertos COM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialport

Estoy con un proyecto de comunicación en serial. Se debe recibir señales de un equipo de monitoreo a través de un puerto COM, tengo desconocimientos sobre ciertos parámetros a configurar. A continuación les muestro el código como defino el puerto serial:

```
SerialPort com = new SerialPort
{
    PortName = "COM1",
    BaudRate = 9600,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    DataBits = 8,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    Handshake = Handshake.None,
    ReadBufferSize = 1024,
    WriteBufferSize = 512,
    ReadTimeout = 0,
    WriteTimeout = 0   
};
```

Según el equipo debo configurar mi equipo con valores como Buffer In = 1024 y Buffer Out = 512 (me imagino que el primero se refiere ReadBufferSize y el segundo a WriteBufferSize), luego tengo un parámetro llamado "termination" cuyo valor es 020.

Donde va o se define ese parámetro?

Gracias de antemano...